# Project-wide additional library paths -- MSVS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, libraries

I'm setting up a VC++ project in MS Visual Studio 2008 that'll be used by several people. I wanted to keep things as simple as possible so I've set up Additional Include Directories via the Project properties. I've also set up additional library files via Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories.

However, my issue is that I really need to set up Additional library PATHs, because I am using an SDK which does inline linking of libraries.

I could just tell each one of the participants to manually add the library path to their MSVS2008 environment, but it would be handy if I could integrate the RELATIVE library path in the project itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set additional library paths in your project properties: 
Project Properties | Configuration Properties | Linker | General | Additional Library Directories

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks Sean. I'll most likely end up doing exactly this for now and look in to using Property Sheets for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [Property Sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e.aspx) instead.  They allow you a lot of flexibility in setting paths and other project properties that are common between projects.

You can create a property sheet that has a user macro for the absolute path to the SDK.  That user macro can then be used to set the additional library paths in the property sheet.  This way, you only need to modify the absolute path in one place and it will apply to all of your projects.

The global "VC++ Directories" feature has been removed in Visual Studio 2010 (it's been replaced by a set of base property sheets).